# How can I do for my Items inside a ListView start at the right to left?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, telerik

I want make my Items inside a ListView going right to left.
At the moment I have default settings:

[image]

As you can see I have a hole in the right and I want to reverse this, put a hole in the left.
Hope you understand the problem.

```
 <telerikDataControls:RadListView ItemsSource="{Binding CatalogSizes, Source={x:Reference ExtendedContentView}}" >
    <telerikDataControls:RadListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <listView:ListViewTemplateCell>
                <listView:ListViewTemplateCell.View>
                    <Frame Padding="0" CornerRadius="3.5" BackgroundColor="{Binding IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource Batata}, ConverterParameter={x:Reference Name=MainColorGrid}}">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Quantity}" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                     </Frame>
                 </listView:ListViewTemplateCell.View>
             </listView:ListViewTemplateCell>
          </DataTemplate>
      </telerikDataControls:RadListView.ItemTemplate>
      <telerikDataControls:RadListView.LayoutDefinition>
          <listView:ListViewGridLayout SpanCount="3" HorizontalItemSpacing="3" />
       </telerikDataControls:RadListView.LayoutDefinition>
</telerikDataControls:RadListView>
```

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: Sorry, forgot about that part, I just have edited the question. @Jason

Answer (score -1):

You can change the Direction, to RTL. In CSS is just:

```
 direction: rtl;
```

You can see a sample [here](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/xamarin-forms-theming-with-css-and-telerik-ui).

Comment: So I tried that css with `HorizontalOptions="End"` and turn my items invisible but still in same position, I can saw that because when I click on them appear me the button click animation, and without `HorizontalOptions="End"` give my SystemNullReference.

Comment: @EdPlunkett do you have any suggestion?

Comment: This is CSS styling, per the documentation. Dunno why the downvotes, but whatever.